# Deadlock - Creating a QThread from the main thread

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

I am trying to debug a situation where 2 threads have been locked on the same mutex(QMutex).
The connection between the two threads is -one thread is created from another.
i.e. 
First is the main thread( gui thread) , from which i create a another object of an user defined class. From the constructor of this object a new thread is created.
Is it a wrong usage ?

```
//Some part of Code:

void main()
{
  MyMainThread *obj = new MyMainThread(); // this class inherits QWidget
}

//This class declaration is in another file
class Someobj
{
  SomeObj()
  {
  }
  StartAnotherObjThread()
  {
     AnotherObjthread obj = new AnotherObjThread(this);
     obj->start();       
  }
}

MyMainThread()
{
  SomeObj *obj = new SomeObj();
  obj->StartAnotherObjThread();
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted some code.

Comment: If possible please share whole code, where is mutex? and how threads are sync ...

Comment: I recommend reading the [Qt 5 thread documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#details) which is just so more useful and better practice than what the very outdated Qt 4 documentation says. The mechanics described for Qt 5 are valid for Qt 4 as well.

Comment: What is AnotherObjThread ?